# Python найти максимально схожую строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, циклы, кортежи

Есть список кортежей:

```
[('Наборы еды',), ('Все для рыбалки',), ('Цветоводство',), ('Интерьер',), ('Пчеловодство',), ('Новый Год',)]
```

И например есть переменная:

```
user_message = "Новйы Гдо"
```

Нужно вернуть максимально похожее значение (в моем случае это "Новый год"). 
Нужен конкретный пример, например с использованием *Расстояния Левенштейна*. 
Я пытался, но у меня не получилось из-за проблемы с циклом, который я не смог правильно построить, так что надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import difflib

def similar(seq1, seq2):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=seq1.lower(), b=seq2.lower()).ratio()

myList = [('Наборы еды',), ('Все для рыбалки',), ('Цветоводство',), ('Интерьер',), ('Пчеловодство',), ('Новый Год',)]

user_message = "Новйы Гдо"
print(user_message, sorted([ [ [ similar(j, user_message), j ] for j in i ] for i in myList ], reverse=True)[0])
Новйы Гдо [[0.7777777777777778, 'Новый Год']]

user_message = "Новый Гдо"
print(user_message, sorted([ [ [ similar(j, user_message), j ] for j in i ] for i in myList ], reverse=True)[0])
Новый Гдо [[0.8888888888888888, 'Новый Год']]

user_message = "Новый год"
print(user_message, sorted([ [ [ similar(j, user_message), j ] for j in i ] for i in myList ], reverse=True)[0])
Новый год [[1.0, 'Новый Год']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно как вариант попробовать [yandex speller](https://github.com/oriontvv/pyaspeller) на 100% не уверен в коректности, но более менее связаные слова он может сделать

```
import pyaspeller


def spelled(t):
    speller = pyaspeller.YandexSpeller(lang='ru', find_repeat_words=False,
                                       ignore_digits=True)
    return speller.spell(t)


text = [i[0].lower() for i in
        [('Наборы еды',), ('Все для рыбалки',), ('Цветоводство',), ('Интерьер',), ('Пчеловодство',), ('Новый Год',)]]

user_message = "Новйы Гдо"

speller_text = " ".join([i["s"][0] for i in spelled(user_message)]).lower()
print(speller_text) # новый год
print(speller_text in text) # True
```